# ERROR:Unresolved external Symbol of d2d1effects.h CLSID_D2D1HueRotation property in DIRECTX

Tags: c++, c, directx, directx-11, unresolved-external

I have an error 
`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_D2D1HueRotation`
I can't understand why I get this error. 
The error is on 4th line of the code `CLSID_D2D1HueRotation`.
This is the code...

```
float width = 350;
    float height = 100;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1Effect> hueRotationEffect;

    context2->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1HueRotation, &hueRotationEffect);

    hueRotationEffect->SetInput(0, tetronimoBitmap.Get());
    hueRotationEffect->SetValue(D2D1_HUEROTATION_PROP_ANGLE, 270.0f);

    rectImage = { width,height, width + tetronimoBitmap->GetSize().width, height + tetronimoBitmap->GetSize().height };
    //context2->CreateBitmapBrush(tetronimoBitmap.Get(), tetronimoBitmapBrush.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf());

    context2->DrawImage(hueRotationEffect.Get());

    //context2->FillRectangle(rectImage, tetronimoBitmapBrush.Get());
    //context2->DrawBitmap(tetronimoBitmap.Get(), &rectImage, 1.0f, D2D1_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, NULL);
    if (FAILED(context2->EndDraw())) {
        context2->EndDraw();
    }
```

Comment: Are you linking `d2d1.lib, dxguid.lib` libs? [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/hue-rotate)

Comment: In my external dependencies i have d2d1effects.h file and when i put mouse on the property it recognizes the GUID prop

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to link `d2d1.lib, dxguid.lib`. Thanks kiran Biradar.

Comment: You should have asked Kiran Biradar to post his comment as an answer, which you can then mark as correct.